# Django 1.9 TemplateSyntaxError Could not parse the remainder: '==' from 'game.status=='

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble figuring out where the problem is here.

Essentially I am trying to pass a Context, which is a dictionary of named keys mapped to a list of Game objects, to an html snippet via render. Each game in the list is of the Game class which has a single char status field. I have a 'for' loop over the list of games So I am trying to use the 'if' tags to access the status and display a message accordingly. The problem comes when rendering the snippet, and giving me an error:`TemplateSyntaxError at /user/home
Could not parse the remainder: '==' from 'game.status=='`

I believe this has to do with trying to access the Game's status attribute. 
Here is some of the code for the class:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    first_player = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="games_first_player")
    second_player = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="games_second_player")
    next_to_move = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="games_to_move")
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_active = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, default="A", choices=GAME_STATUS_CHOICES)

    objects = GamesManager()
```

Here is the view generating the list and passing it to render

```
def home(request):
    my_games = Game.objects.games_for_user(request.user)
    active_games = my_games.filter(status="A")
    finished_games = my_games.exclude(status="A")
    waiting_games = active_games.filter(next_to_move=request.user)
    other_games = active_games.exclude(next_to_move=request.user)
    context = Context({'other_games': other_games,
                       'waiting_games': waiting_games,
                       'finished_games': finished_games})
    return render(request, 'user/home.html', context)
```

and here is the pertinent part of  user/home.html

```
        <h3> Here is your current overview:</h3>

    {% block content %}
      <div class="well col-md-6">
          {% include "tictactoe/game_list_snippet.html" with header="Games Awaiting Your Move" games_list=waiting_games %}
          {% include "tictactoe/game_list_snippet.html" with header="Waiting Games" games_list=other_games %}
          {% include "tictactoe/game_list_snippet.html" with header="Finished Games" games_list=finished_games %}
      </div>
    {%  endblock content %}
```

and finally here is the snippet

```
<div class="list-group">
{% for game in games_list %}
    <a class="list-group-item" href="#">
    {{ game }}:
    {% if game.status == "A" %}
      {% if game.next_to_move == user %}Your Turn{% else %} Waiting for opponents turn {% endif %}
    {% elif game.status== "D" %}
      Draw
    {% elif game.status== "F" and user == game.first_player %}
      You Won!
    {% elif game.status== "S" and user == game.second_player %}
      You Won!
    {% else %}
      You Lost.
    {% endif %}
    <span class='badge'>{{game.move_set_count}}</span></a>
{% empty %}
  <span class="list-group-item">No Games Available.</span>
{% endfor %}
```

In the interest of full disclosure, I got most of this code from working through a django course on Pluralsight. Unfortunately he is using django 1.5 and i have 1.9, and this isn't the first time there have been issues with deprecations/additions/changes, but this is the first I haven't been able to find an answer in the docs or here. I am pretty sure that the problem is in the template logic in the {% if %} tags because if I cut that out, the {% for %} loop works and the page shows the correct list of games. I realize that this post is very long and I just want to say that any/all help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some of the statements in Django templates look like Python, but Django actually implements its own parsing logic which does not work exactly like Python does. In this case, it's not capable of parsing an `==` condition that is not separated by a space from what you are comparing. So `game.status==` just needs to be `game.status ==`

Comment: That worked. Lol it was so simple, I tried that with one of the statements but not the rest and the django debugger kept highlighting the same line... thanks a lot tho mayne.